# Unable to fetch xml node using XDocument.Element

Tags: c#, xml

Here is a sample XML wherein I want to fetch xml node.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");

<Rootelement>
    <element1 />
    <element2 />
    <element2 />
    <element3 />
</Rootelement>
```

I want to find out element2 from the xml

Here is my code snippet.

```
var xElement = XDoc.Element("Rootelement").Element("element2");
```

but I shows null. I do not have any namespace in xml and I can't include one.

Please help.

Comment: If you want the 2nd element try : doc.Root.Elements().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(myXmlString);

    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
      string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
      string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
      Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
    }
```

This code will return all the values of the tag `<firstName>` and `<LastName>`.
If you only want one value then you can remove the foreach loop and you are good to go.

Here is the xml code

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>White</LastName>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
var xElement = doc.Root.Element("element2");
```

If you want to find elements anywhere in the document
Use;

```
doc.Descendants("element2")
```

Comment: Did you share complete xml to us?